# How to make a Windows Mobile based WinForms .Net application easily changeable?

Tags: windows-mobile

I need to build a Win Mobile WinForms .Net application that once developed will be easy to morph or adjust to new user requirements quickly (including changes in GUI).
The main objective is to minimize the development time (development to production roll-out effort). 
Also, a nice thing to have is to be able to test it in an automated way.

The application must be able to:
1) Persist state (may use a local database);
2) Sync data across (via Radio or WiFi);
3) Exchange info with a desktop PC or a central server;

Comment: This is way, way too broad and you've not asked any specific questions.  Basically most anything that would apply to software anywhere else (PC or otherwise) would be applicable. You haven't even mentioned a programming language.  This is also pretty subjective so making it a wiki would give some chance of some form of suggestions.

Comment: The language of choice is any .Net CLR based, but seems to me C# has proliferated more into the programming-sphere. For example, any IoC or MVC container/framework would be c# centric (in my observations). I am looking more at best practices at this point.